# How to Switch between Wifi and BLE on a Arduino nano IoT?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi, arduino-nano

I have got both BLE working to configure and setup the nano IoT, and WIFI working to send sensor data to a cloud DB.

I've found on Arduino Forum a possible solution it it
https://forum.arduino.cc/t/coexistence-of-wifi-and-ble-in-arduino-nano-33-iot/676169

However I has a memory leak problem: every time I switch back to BLE it consumes roughly 500bytes of memory. This means all memory is exhausted within one hour or so and the Nano IoT crashes

[image]

Has anyone merged the two ideas. Have the Nano 33 IoT connected with both Wifi and BLE?

I know BLE and Wifi can't work in parallel on this board but can you easily and quickly switch between the two ?.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I've found an answer to the memory leak problem on the ArduinoBLE library:

It looks like the issue comes from the following file:

```
.\libraries\ArduinoBLE\src\utility\GATT.cpp
```

In `void GATTClass::begin()` a some objects are created with new. However they are not deleted in `void GATTClass::end()`.

So the method need to be updated as follows:

```
void GATTClass::end()
{
  delete( _genericAccessService );
  delete( _deviceNameCharacteristic );
  delete( _appearanceCharacteristic );
  delete( _genericAttributeService );
  delete( _servicesChangedCharacteristic );
 _attributes.clear();
}
```

There's an open issue on GitHub
https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE/issues/192

Now back to the part of switch between BLE and WiFI. This is how to do it:

```
//Start Wifi
  wiFiDrv.wifiDriverDeinit();
  wiFiDrv.wifiDriverInit();
  status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  server.begin();

//...

// End Wifi    

  WiFi.end()     

//...

//Start BLE
    BLE.begin();
    BLE.scan(); 

//...

// End BLE
   BLE.stopAdvertise();   //don't think this is needed as I am reading other BLE devices
   BLE.stopScan();
   BLE.end();
```

`BLEservice` and `BLEcharacteristics` are done on the `setup()` part of the code.